# How to get the the object from its instance field java?

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say I have two classes Animal and Food:

```
   public class Animal {
        String animalName = "";
        Food animalFood;
        public Animal(String animalName, Food food) {
            this.animalFood = animalFood;
            this.animalName = animalName;
        }
    }

    public class Food {
        String foodType;
        String foodName;
        public Food(String foodType, String foodName) {
            this.foodName = foodName;
            this.foodType = foodType;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Food dogFood = new Food("meat", "beef");
        Animal animal = new Animal("Max", dogFood);
        //problem: get animal from dogfood
    }
```

Is there anyway, through Reflection or otherwise to get an instance of a class from its fields (assuming that you have access to the fields)?
Edit: The example obviously isn't the real problem, so lets say I only have the `dogfood` instance which is created from an anynomous Instance of `Animal` (`animal` in this case) how do I get animal from it?

Comment: What's the end goal here, what are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: The end goal is getting the anynomous instances from its known instance fields.

Comment: Can the downvoter please specify the problem with the question so I can improve it, thank you.

Comment: i can't relate your code sample to what you are asking (i'm not the downvoter btw)

Comment: Yeah I'm still confused about the goal.  Please edit the question to provide more details about what you are trying to achieve.  Right now this question is confusing because you are hinting at _how_ to do it which makes no sense.

Comment: Edited the question, if you have an anynomous instance and you had access to only one of its instance fields, how do you get the anynomous instance from that field, I think this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you're trying to do is this:

Given

```
public class Animal {
        String animalName = "";
        Food animalFood;
        public Animal(String animalName, Food food) {
            this.animalFood = animalFood;
            this.animalName = animalName;
        }
    }
```

And then something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Food dogFood = new Food("meat", "beef");
        doSomethingWithAnimal(new Animal("Max", dogFood)); // <-- anonymous creation of an Animal
        //problem: get animal from dogfood
        Animal theAnonymousAnimal = //get it via reflection from dogFood
    }
```

No, this isn't possible. `Food` does not contain a reference to `Animal` therefore you cannot. If `Food` had an `Animal` field and in the `Animal` constructor you set that reference, then yes, you could via normal reflection.

Comment: Oh that's what I was asking for, thank you, I don't know what was so hard about it to understand. Still disapointed for not having a mechanism to do this though +1

Comment: @GherbiHicham depending on your JVM implementation, it may be possible, but there's no standardized Java API for doing this.